# Can't subscribe to events in Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two Checkbox directives that I'm making: `fancyCheckBox` and, `checkAllCheckbox`. I'm trying to add an event broadcast to the check all so that the fancy checkboxes (there will be many) will hear the event and check themselves if they match the criteria.

Here's my fancyCheckBox:

```
myDir.directive('fancyCheckBox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            isDomain: '=isDomain',
            domain: '=domainId',
            url: '=urlId',
            reason: '@reason',
            clickCb: '&clickCb',
            startChecked: '=isChecked'
        },
        template: '<input type="checkbox" data-ng-click="toggleMe()" data-ng-model="isChecked" />',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.isChecked = angular.copy(scope.startChecked);
            scope.toggleMe = function() {
                scope.isChecked = (!scope.isChecked);
                scope.$eval(scope.clickCb(scope));
            }
            scope.$on('checkAllEvent', function() { // Error on this line
                console.log('Herd a check all event');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The line `scope.on('checkAllEvent'` is producing this error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'on'"

And here's my check all checkbox:

```
myDir.directive('checkAllCheckbox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            reason: '@reason',
            clickCb: '&clickCb',
            startChecked: '=isChecked'
        },
        template: '<input type="checkbox" data-ng-click="checkAll()" data-ng-model="isChecked" />',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.isChecked = (scope.startChecked) ? angular.copy(scope.startChecked) : false;
            scope.checkAll = function() {
                scope.isChecked = (!scope.isChecked);
                scope.$eval(function() {
                scope.$eval(function() {
                    scope.$broadcast('checkAllEvent');
                    scope.clickCb(scope)
                });
            });
        }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Any idea why I can't seem to broadcast or subscribe to events in my directive?

---

EDIT. I changed `scope.on` and `scope.broadcast` to `scope.$on` and `scope.$broadcast`. This stopped the error but my fancyCheckBox is still not receiving the event. Any ideas? I imagine it's because it isn't in the right scope but I don't know how to get it there.

Comment: try `scope.$broadcast` instead of `scope.broadcast` and `scope.$on` instead of `scope.on`

Comment: and `scope.$on` instead of `scope.on`.

Comment: You should use rootscope to broadcast stuff you are not sure the scope of: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using $rootScope?

```
            $scope.$eval(function() {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('checkAllEvent');
                scope.clickCb(scope)
            });
```

EDIT:

You may need to inject $rootScope into your directive

```
myDir.directive('checkAllCheckbox', function($rootScope) {...
```

Comment: I didnt realize you could just add $rootScope to a directive. Way to miss the obvious I guess. Thanks so much this solved my whole issue.

Comment: Don't you just love accepted answers without even an upvote from the person who asked and accepted the answer... @RachelD

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your updated question:

$broadcast dispatches an event name **downwards** to all **child scopes (and their children)** notifying the registered $on listeners. The event life cycle starts at the scope on which $broadcast was called.

$emit dispatches an event name **upwards** through the scope hierarchy notifying the registered $on listeners. The event life cycle starts at the scope on which $emit was called.

In other words, if your `checkAllCheckbox` directive scope is parent to your `fancyCheckBox` directive scope, use $broadcast, if it is a child, use $emit, if it is on the same scope use either $broadcast or $emit, or if you do not no beforehand the hierarchy use $broadcast directly on $rootScope.